# Jpg to PDF conversion problem C# iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, jpeg, file-conversion

I have a problem that I can't solve at the moment.

After converting a JPG image to PDF with iTextSharp, I get this error message "an error occurred while reading a stream" when I open the PDF file with Adobe Reader but when I open it with Foxit or Chrome, I have no problem.

I am not allowed to modify the image or convert it, I have to convert my JPG directly to PDF.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

I have attached the JPG image and my code.

[image]

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

namespace ConvertToPdf_2021
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string imgName = @".\Images\20000002.jpg";

            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@".\Result\20000002.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew));

            doc.Open();

            Image img = Image.GetInstance(imgName);

            double w = img.Width * (0.24);
            double h = img.Height * (0.24);

            img.ScaleAbsoluteHeight((float)h);
            img.ScaleAbsoluteWidth((float)w);

            doc.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            doc.SetPageSize(new Rectangle((float)w, (float)h));
            doc.NewPage();
            doc.Add(img);
            doc.AddTitle("20000002.pdf");

            doc.Close();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I'm totally unsure if this might be your problem or not, but you are not closing your `FileStream`.  Extract the `new FileStream` to a variable (before calling `PdfWriter.GetInstance`) and make sure to call `Close` on it (or dispose it)  after you have closed the `PdfWriter`. You don't have any guarantee that the file stream is closing properly (and -all- its contents are written to disk) unless you explicitly closing it

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already tried what you just told me but it didn't work. I think the problem is with the JPG file. I have tested several free conversion libraries but I still have the same problem with some JPG images and when I tested paid libraries, it works fine.